# How to profile a Linux executable's static memory usage?

Tags: c++, memory-management, static

I'm part of a team of developers who wrote a rather elaborate set of C++-based daemons, of which a dozen or so instances of which run simultaneously on a x86-based Xenomai/real-time Linux server.

The daemons are all compiled together into a single executable (BusyBox-style), whose main() function checks argv[1] and (based on its value) calls the appropriate daemon's subdaemonname_main() function.

I noticed the other day (by doing a "ps -ww -eio pid,%mem,rss,args" on the Linux server) that each of the processes takes up about 35 megabytes of RAM on the server, even if the process is doing nothing but sleeping at the very top of main().  For comparison, if I compile "hello world" (as a separate executable), ps shows that its process takes up practically no RAM.

The lesson I take from that is:  the downside of compiling a number of C++ programs into a single executable like this is that each process that executable runs in will set up all the static/global objects declared in all of the .cpp files, even the ones that will never be used by the particular sub-daemon the process will run.  This is a waste of RAM, and I was able to find a couple of large static C++ objects in the code and change them to be non-static to reduce RAM usage.

My question is, is there any (semi-)automated way for me to get an inventory of what composes that 35MB/process of before-main() memory usage?  I can sort of do it by groveling through every .cpp file manually looking for static or global object declarations, but since it's a big codebase that would take quite a long time, and I might still miss something.  Is there a quick way to profile the process's static-object-memory tables somehow?  Having that information would give me a better idea of where the best opportunities for further reducing RAM usage might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the link map (ld --print-map, or gcc -Wl,--print-map if you're linking with gcc), it should give you some idea re. which static objects went into the final executable.

Sure you get all of them in .data if they were declared that way. The linker has no way to tell some data will never be used, so it has to map everything.

Probably the only simple way to avoid this in reasonably readable C++ is placing "statics" in the stack, specifically the stack of their respective main_*() functions, and passing pointers. That's assuming "statics" are mostly empty. Any actualy static data will still be in .data and there's no way to avoid it.

With some black ELF magic, it may be possible to have dedicated .data sections and map them on demand, but I strongly suspect it's not worth the effort. Especially with C++ and its quirks.